# How to set the path to the tags file?

Tags: linux, vim, ctags

I've tried to set the path to my project's `ctags` file each time when I close the *.c file and go to terminal. I want the tags file to have been set when I open my code file.

Or, maybe ... can I set the tags file only for special directory?

Comment: What is your editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the path of the ctags file is not put in `~/.bashrc` but rather in your editor's config file.

For vim, for example, usually the following lines are put in `~/.vimrc`:

```
set tags+=tags
set tags+=.tags
set tags+=../tags
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you found this post answering your question, please accept it.